# How send post data just string?

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api2

I try to send data by POST:

```
{settings: "settingsJson"}
```

And i have action

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostSettings(int projectId, [FromBody]string settings)
```

settings is null

angular call:

```
projectResource.saveSettings({ projectId: projectId }, { settings: "settingsJson" });
```

I can send array and bind to list, but **I want to send just string**

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
projectResource.saveSettings({ projectId: projectId }, JSON.stringify({ settings: "settingsJson" }));
```